# Member of class point to member of class

Tags: c++

I just started with c++, and i have a problem with pointing to an address of memeber of class.
When i compile  there are no errors, but program breaks when I run it.

```
class vise
{
public:
    int h1=10;
    int n1=12;
    int *x;
    int set();
};

class vodv 
{
public:
    vise *v;
    int g;
};

int vise::set()
{
    h1=5;
    return 0;
}
```

this line break the program

```
vodv f;
vise v1;
(f.v)->x=&(v1.n1);
```

Comment: Could you please provide **all** the needed codes for us to reproduce the crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allocating memory for `v`, and so when you try to access it:

```
(f.v)->x = &(v1.n1);
     ^^^
   Dereferences 'v'
```

`v` can point to any memory address. Dereferencing it is **undefined behavior**, which sometimes (it is undefined after all) crashes your program.